# MBP - have to re-enable Wi-Fi every 30 mins

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, dns

I have a MacBook Pro running on El Capitan (but the issue was already present before the upgrade, so it's not related). I have the Mac since a bit less than a year.
It is still running perfectly but since a couple of weeks, the internet is really weird. It's constantly completely blocked and just not working.
The wifi works well: on my iPhone it is never down, but every 30min or so, it just blocks while I am browsing (but the issue is there on all the apps used, from Xcode to my FTP client, and so on), and it doesn't work anymore.
When I just turn the wifi off and on again, it works well for some time, and then the issue comes back again.

I tried changing the DNS (by using this software that indicates the fastest DNS to use) and I thought it worked at first, but the issues are back again.

I have tried deleting the wifi from my keychain and adding it again the problem is persisting.

Obviously I have restarted the modem a couple of times too, no difference.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a Cron action who turn on/off your wifi connection every 30 minutes ;)

**Turn Wifi Off**

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
```

**Turn Wifi On**

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

http://blog.mattcrampton.com/post/64144666914/managing-wifi-connections-using-the-mac-osx

**Schedule a Cron task :**

http://benr75.com/pages/using_crontab_mac_os_x_unix_linux

Edit : Ohh sorry I was thinking that you wanted to turn on/off your wifi every 30 minutes :/ However, if you don't find a solution...

Comment: Cron on OSX? Blasphemy... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html